# SPSS sort variables within cases

Tags: sorting, spss, ranking

I need to find a way in SPSS to create new variables based on a set of variables where the scores are sorted from low to high within a case.
e.g.these are the starting variables

```
Var1 Var2 Var3
3     2    1
4     2    5
```

I need to be able to create new variables as below where the answers are sorted within a row.

```
rVar1 rVar2 rVar3
1      2     3
2      4     5
```

Is there a way to do this in SPSS?

Thank you

RANKING VARIABLES only sorts within a variable, but not across variables within a case.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to flip the data (turn rows to columns and vice versa), then sort it, and flip it back:
First I recreate your example in a new dataset:
dataset close all.

```
data list free /Var1 Var2 Var3 (3F1).
begin data
    3 8 1 4 2 5
end data.
```

Now to sort columns by rows:

```
flip.
delete variables CASE_LBL.
sort cases by all.
flip.
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this feedback! I have additional variables in addition which need to be kept, so I don't think that flipping will work here.

Comment: It is possible to separate the above data from other colums, re-order it like above, then re-attach it to the original data.